# Android home screen widget

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget

I am doing the widget development first time. So please bear with me. I have an Android service that starts the widget from `onStart()`. So I am in my `WidgetProvider` class `onUpdate()` and update the views like buttons.
Now my question is -

1) How do I handle press of buttons in widget and tell the service about button press so that service does its work?

2) After the service has done its work, it needs to update the widget buttons and how do I handle this?

3) When the app is killed, the service is also killed. So when I click on widget, how do I determine that app is killed and open the app?

4) If the UI in app is talking to service and receiving responses from service, how do I tell these responses to widget too?

My widget code is like this -

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName componentName;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        componentName = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "Play",componentName));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "Pause",componentName));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if ("Play".equals(intent.getAction())) {

        //I really dont know what to do here....

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            RemoteViews remoteViews;
            ComponentName watchWidget;

            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);



          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

        }
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action, ComponentName componentName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, componentName);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
}
```

Request you to please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're already doing that with your `getPendingSelfIntent()` method. Although your target should be `MyWidgetProvider` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
```

Then in your `onReceive` you will check if the intent action is "Play" and start your service from there:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
```

2) In order to your service communicate to your Widget you need to send a broadcast:

```
Intent widgetUpdateIntent = new Intent(this, MyWidgetProvider.class);
widgetUpdateIntent.setAction(ApplicationEvents.DATA_FETCHED);//this is your custom action
widgetUpdateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
sendBroadcast(widgetUpdateIntent);
```

3) You don't need to explicit open the app (you can't do that, actually), if you have your update cycle set to 30 mins you will receive the `onUpdate` callback and you need to start your service from there too.

4) You will update the UI in the `onReceive` event when the action matches your custom action (`ApplicationEvents.DATA_FETCHED`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) in the 3rd point, I actually have my android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
in xml file. But I have seen Spotify wherein when the app is killed and you click on the widget, they explicitly open the app.

Comment: Note that the minimum value is 30 minutes as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis). In order to use a lower value you need to use the AlarmManager. About Spotify, when you click on the widget is a different scenario because the widget provider will handle the intent so it's not related to the scheduled update.

Comment: Yeah  I also need similar to Spotify.  I dont need scheduled update.  How do I do this?

Comment: If you set the property `android:updatePeriodMillis` to zero you will disable the update every 30 mins, for instance. If you only need to do something when the user clicks on a button you just need to set a pending intent with an action (Play or Pause) and handle them on the `onReceive` event.

Comment: Oh thats great info :) So when the app is killed and service is killed, I want to grey out the buttons in widget. So user when he clicks on widget, must open the app and the app will create the service. How do I do this?

Comment: What kind of service do you have, a Started or a IntentService? A started service runs in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed.

Comment: A started service...This service is killed when the app is killed

Comment: So what you probably need is a Started Service, check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).